# Vue JS dynamic html v-model binding

Tags: html, vue.js, model-view-controller, v-model

I have integrated Vue Js in the main MVC application. I have a requirement wherein at some place, dynamic html is loading from partial view. I want to bind vue js v-model into this dynamic html.
For example, in my partial view, I have :

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" v-model="user.firstName" />
```

Now when I get the html from partial view and load it either by v-html or by jquery html(''), it is not binding vue js model.

Please guide on this.

Comment: Try binding the html first and instantiate the vuejs after the render

Comment: please provide an example if any

Comment: It is like after loading the view in mvc, on click of a button, a html will be served from the controller. In that html, there is a v-model

Comment: `v-html` will not handle the bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by :

```
const vue2 = {                        
              template: nodeData.NodeProperties,
              el: "#app2"
             };
new Vue(vue2).$mount();
```